# R output to GraphPad Prism9 input

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```r
data <- structure(list(num_day = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), `719989_Cre+` = c(92.1511909722222, 
94.5288888888889, 96.006, 100.267694444444, 96.758375), `719990_Cre+` = c(91.4173298611111, 
91.0037916666667, 91.4484652777778, 97.7569166666667, 90.118421875
), `719991_Cre-` = c(91.3601006944444, 90.7093888888889, 90.8267152777778, 
99.0522708333333, 94.59484375), `719992_Cre-` = c(91.7124270833333, 
93.6639722222222, 94.3707152777778, 103.578034722222, 94.34934375
), `719993_Cre+` = c(98.4150572916667, 101.066902777778, 101.714888888889, 
105.751506944444, 98.085171875), `719994_Cre+` = c(92.4319878472222, 
94.7451944444445, 95.1398819444444, 101.827854166667, 101.32921875
), `720447_Cre+` = c(96.5950538194444, 93.8613333333333, 95.7006388888889, 
100.318381944444, 102.746578125), `720448_Cre-` = c(90.2171024305556, 
90.538375, 91.0464097222222, 95.9593333333333, 93.084515625)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to use R to write this data into a format that I can easily copy into Prism9 for analysis, something that looks like this:
[image: Preferred output for input into GraphPad Prims9 software]

Is this possible in R? Anybody have any ideas? Preferably using `tidyverse` but i'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just sorting the columns by `Cre` status, which ends up getting me pretty close to the answer I need. I just write this to a tsv file and then copy it into prism (removing the numbers on the front of the column title).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(reprex)

res <- data %>%
  dplyr::select(num_day, contains("Cre+"), contains("Cre-"))
res
#> # A tibble: 5 × 9
#>   num_day `719989_Cre+` 719990…¹ 71999…² 71999…³ 72044…⁴ 71999…⁵ 71999…⁶ 72044…⁷
#>     <dbl>         <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1       0          92.2     91.4    98.4    92.4    96.6    91.4    91.7    90.2
#> 2       1          94.5     91.0   101.     94.7    93.9    90.7    93.7    90.5
#> 3       2          96.0     91.4   102.     95.1    95.7    90.8    94.4    91.0
#> 4       3         100.      97.8   106.    102.    100.     99.1   104.     96.0
#> 5       4          96.8     90.1    98.1   101.    103.     94.6    94.3    93.1
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​`719990_Cre+`, ²​`719993_Cre+`,
#> #   ³​`719994_Cre+`, ⁴​`720447_Cre+`, ⁵​`719991_Cre-`, ⁶​`719992_Cre-`,
#> #   ⁷​`720448_Cre-`
reprex()
#> ℹ Non-interactive session, setting `html_preview = FALSE`.
#> CLIPR_ALLOW has not been set, so clipr will not run interactively
#> Error in switch(where, expr = stringify_expression(x_expr), clipboard = ingest_clipboard(), : EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>